# Fullcalendar modal button click runs more times

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

I have a problem with button click in modal (using `FullCalendar`).

My plan is:

1. Click on event
2. Modal appears with 3 options
3. Confirm changes a value in mysql database / Refuse changes a value in mysql database

When I try one time is works very well. But when I close the modal and open an other i click on the refuse/confirm button then it runs more times (2, 4 ...).
What is the problem??

modal:

```
<div id="eventContent" title="Event Details" style="display:none;">
    Name: <span id="name"></span><br>
    Start: <span id="startTime"></span><br>
    End: <span id="endTime"></span><br><br>
    <p id="eventInfo"></p>
    <button id="confirm_button" type="button">Confirm</button>
    <button id="refuse_button" type="button">Refuse</button>
    <button type="close_button">Close</button>
</div>
```

eventRender:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'prev title next',
                right: ''
            },
            events: "http://localhost/calendar_directory/calendar_db_connect.php",
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                element.click(function () {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "YYYY-MM-DD");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "YYYY-MM-DD");

                    $("#name").html(event.title);
                    $("#startTime").html(start);
                    $("#endTime").html(end);
                    $("#eventContent").dialog({modal: true, title: event.title, width: 350});


                    $("#refuse_button").click(function ()
                    {
                        var id = event._id;
                        var confirmed_number = 2;
                        var decision = confirm("Do you really want to refuse that?");

                        if (decision)
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://localhost/calendar_directory/confirm_events.php",
                                data: '&id=' + id + '&confirmed_number=' + confirmed_number,
                                type: "POST",
                                success: function (json)
                                {
                                    console.log(id);
                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    $("#confirm_button").click(function ()
                    {
                        var id = event._id;
                        var confirmed_number = 1;
                        var decision = confirm("Do you really want to confirm that?");
                        if (decision)
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "http://localhost/calendar_directory/confirm_events.php",
                                data: '&id=' + id + '&confirmed_number=' + confirmed_number,
                                type: "POST",
                                success: function (json) {
                                    console.log("confirmed");
                                    return;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                });
            },

        });
    });
</script>
```

[Database structure here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Spis.jpg)

confirmed column can be: 0,1 or 2

Comment: notice: every click repeats.
1, modal appears-> click on refuse -> refuse ok-> close,
2, modal appears-> click on refuse ->  -> refuse ok-> refuse ok-> close,
3,modal appears-> click on refuse -> refuse ok-> refuse ok -> refuse ok-> close,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigned the same handler to the click event.

The solution is:

```
$("#refuse_button").unbind("click").click(function(){
    /*Your code goes here*/
}
$("#confirm_button").unbind("click").click(function(){
    /*Your code goes here*/
}
```